# Can't get async closure to work with Warp::Filter

Tags: rust, closures, rust-warp

I am trying to get an async closure working in the `and_then` filter from `Warp`.

This is the smallest example I could come up with where I am reasonably sure I didn't leave any important details out:

```rust
use std::{convert::Infallible, sync::Arc, thread, time};
use tokio::sync::RwLock;
use warp::Filter;

fn main() {
    let man = Manifest::new();

    let check = warp::path("updates").and_then(|| async move { GetAvailableBinaries(&man).await });
}

async fn GetAvailableBinaries(man: &Manifest) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, Infallible> {
    Ok(warp::reply::json(&man.GetAvailableBinaries().await))
}

pub struct Manifest {
    binaries: Arc<RwLock<Vec<i32>>>,
}

impl Manifest {
    pub fn new() -> Manifest {
        let bins = Arc::new(RwLock::new(Vec::new()));

        thread::spawn(move || async move {
            loop {
                thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10000));
            }
        });

        Manifest { binaries: bins }
    }

    pub async fn GetAvailableBinaries(&self) -> Vec<i32> {
        self.binaries.read().await.to_vec()
    }
}
```

I am using:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
warp = { version = "0.2", features = ["tls"] }
```

The error is:

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
 --> src/main.rs:9:48
  |
9 |     let check = warp::path("updates").and_then(|| async move { GetAvailableBinaries(&man).await });
  |                                       -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------------------------------------ closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `man` out of its environment
  |                                       |        |
  |                                       |        this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
  |                                       the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
```

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: The code in the question does not implement `Clone` for manifest, but you've removed that error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're going for, but this solution builds for me:

```rust
use std::{convert::Infallible, sync::Arc, thread, time};
use tokio::sync::RwLock;
use warp::Filter;

fn main() {
    let man = Manifest::new();

    let check = warp::path("updates").and_then(|| async { GetAvailableBinaries(&man).await });
}

async fn GetAvailableBinaries(man: &Manifest) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, Infallible> {
    Ok(warp::reply::json(&man.GetAvailableBinaries().await))
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Manifest {
    binaries: Arc<RwLock<Vec<i32>>>,
}

impl Manifest {
    pub fn new() -> Manifest {
        let bins = Arc::new(RwLock::new(Vec::new()));

        thread::spawn(move || async {
            loop {
                thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10000));
                //mutate bins here
            }
        });

        Manifest { binaries: bins }
    }

    pub async fn GetAvailableBinaries(&self) -> Vec<i32> {
        self.binaries.read().await.to_vec()
    }
}
```

The `move` here is the reason the compiler gave a warning regarding the signature: `let check = warp::path("updates").and_then(|| async move { GetAvailableBinaries(&man).await });`. This means that everything referenced in this closure will be moved into the context of the closure. In this case, the compiler can't guarantee the closure to be `Fn` but only `FnOnce` meaning that the closure can only be guaranteed to execute once.

Comment: Well this technically allows the code to compile, it doesn’t actually solve the real problem. The real code will most likely have a call to `warp::serve(check)` to start the webserver. That call will impose additional restrictions on `check`

Answer (score 0):

After making `Manifest` implement `Clone`, you can fix the error by balancing when the manifest object is cloned:

```rust
fn main() {
    let man = Manifest::new();

    let check = warp::path("updates").and_then(move || {
        let man = man.clone();
        async move { get_available_binaries(&man).await }
    });

    warp::serve(check);
}
```

This moves `man` into the closure passed to `and_then`, then provides a clone of `man` to the async block each time the closure is executed. The async block then owns that data and can take a reference to it without worrying about executing the future after the data has been deallocated.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. This causes `use of moved value: bins` on the last line of the `impl Manifest` block

Comment: @MatthewGoulart there is no usage of `bins` in `GetAvailableBinaries`, which is the end of the impl block.

Comment: Sorry, the error occurs on the last line of the `new()` fn of the `impl Manifest` block

Comment: I see now, it's because in my real code the thread spawned in `new` *does* use `bins`. This is mostly why I was hesitant to remove much from my original question, I don't know rust well enough to know what is important and what isn't especially when I don't know why an error is occurring.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart you are not extrapolating from the answers you've received. You need to clone `bins` before passing it to the spawned thread. It's the same problem in a different location.